# How to Check if an Address is a Node in a Substrate Blockchain Network?

Tags: substrate-node-template, polkadot, proof-of-stake

I'm working on a Substrate-based blockchain network. I need to verify if a user with a specific address (e.g., 5XDDFFDF...) has added a node to the network. Depending on the verification, I want to either allow or reject certain actions.

How can I programmatically check if an address has added a node to the network in Substrate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The account and node are not bound.

To achieve this, you need to develop a pallet that can store this relationship.

When verification is needed, simply read the storage and check if the account exists in it.

By the way, I think you can use the existing pallet at https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/cc39edd5a84ce14f5a5bfbf3cb949086d18e2c87/substrate/frame/node-authorization/src/lib.rs#L100-L103. However, it provides more features. If you want something simple, it would be better to implement one yourself.

Comment: i dont have the peerID , i just have the AccountId

Comment: You don't have to. User need to do the "bind" action first. Otherwise, you can't know the relationship between an account and a node. And one more thing, you might need to check if there is really a node there.

Comment: I don't need these nodes to be part of the consensus algorithm. I simply want them to join the network, and their primary role is to validate or check the quality of item ( special senario ) .

i think using the node-authorization pallet is good for me . im not sure the nodes that added, bcome part of the consensus or not  and for add node thay have to pay like POS .

Comment: No, it definitely does not produce any proof and does not incorporate the proof into the consensus. It is just a storage of records.